# Sending logs between rsyslog (client) and syslogd (server)

Tags: linux, freebsd, syslog, rsyslog

I have two machines. First of them runs embedded Linux and the second one runs FreeBSD. The machine with Linux has `rsyslog` and needs to be a syslog client. The other one has installed `syslogd` and needs to be a server. The machine with FreeBSD and `syslogd` doesn't write remote logs to a file. When I changed just for test `rsyslog` to `sysklogd` on my Linux machine, remote logging was working. The problem is that I must have `rsyslog` on the client. What can cause the problem? Are `rsyslog` and `syslogd` incompatible with each other? As I know the log message format is the same.

When I run
`tcpdump -enpi <interface>` on FreeBSD I see syslog messages

```
Linux MAC > FreeBSD MAC, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 94: client_IP.35398 > server_IP.514: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 52
```

In my `rsyslog.conf` file on Linux (client) I was added the following line:

```
*.* @server_IP
```

In my `syslog.conf` file on FreeBSD (server) I was added the following lines:

```
+client_IP
*.*  /path/to/client/logs
```

And in my `rc.conf` file on FreeBSD I was added the following lines:

```
syslogd_enable="YES" 
syslogd_flags="-a client_IP -vv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `-a client_IP` from `syslogd_flags` in `rc.conf`. The problem was probably client port number. If the port is not specified in `syslogd_flags` it is assumed to be 514 but my logs were going out from another one. Another solution could be add all ports to client IP address `-a client_IP:*`.